# Search console offline access auth flow with .net client library

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-search-console

I have a C# app that should gather users search console data on a scheduled basis. I would like some verification regarding the auth flow, since I didn't find these specific parts in the docs.

Let's say that a new user wants to connect their search console data. A link is provided for auth:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri=url&client_id=clientId`

`access_type=offline` is set to avoid token expiry.

User is redirected with `code` - application handles it:

```
var codeFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        ClientSecret = clientSecret,
    },
    Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly" },
});

var token = await codeFlow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(null, code, redirectUrl, CancellationToken.None)
// store token.RefreshToken in database for the user
```

On subsequent calls by the application for the user, the stored token is reused:

```
var token = await codeFlow.RefreshTokenAsync(null, theRefreshToken, CancellationToken.None);
var credentials = new UserCredential(codeFlow, null, token);
```

Since this will be run from scheduled jobs, I don't want to reauthenticate the user. Is this implementation correct for my use case?